# how do I post form data and upload file with the JS fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, html, fetch-api

I am trying to post form data using JS fetch API, also i successfully send data and get response , but got an error in file uploaded my file  is not uploaded , and also not get stored filename into database.

```
<form id="signup">
    <label for="myName">Send me your name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myName" name="name" value="abc">
    <br>
    <label for="userId">your id:</label>
    <input type="text" id="userId" name="id" value="123">
    <br>
    <label for="pic">your photo:</label>
    <input id="profile" name="profile" id="profile" type="file">
    <br>
    <input id="postSubmit" type="submit" value="Send Me!">
</form>
```

And javascript code

```
const thisForm = document.getElementById('signup');
    const profile = document.getElementById('profile');
    thisForm.addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(thisForm).entries()
    formdata.append("profile",profile.files[0]);
        const response = await fetch('<?php echo base_url() . 'api/get_subscription' ?>', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
            body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData))
        });

        const result = await response.json();
        console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you are overwriting the default submit you should get the file content via the FileReader API. I'll write an answer as soon as possible, meanwhile try to read that API

Comment: Post the error messages you get when uploading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to transform to JSON, and no need to use `entries()` on FormData. Also check the spelling, you wrote `formdata` which is different than `formData`.

```
const thisForm = document.getElementById('signup');
var formData = new FormData(thisForm);
const profile = document.getElementById('profile');
formData.append("profile", profile.files[0]);
const response = await fetch('<?php echo base_url() . 'api/get_subscription' ?>', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
  body: formData
});
```

Comment: it's working , but without use of JSON I am able to collect whole data but ,when I send  it to my php api , it storing as blank value

Answer (score 1):

For file uploading, you need Content-type `multipart/form-data`. Or just leave out Content-type, because your browser will probably automatically set this.

Comment: Now I am getting in console log {
  "name": "Abc",
  "id": "123",
  "profile": {},
}