# Using HTML input to create FormData obj for file upload

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an `<input type="file">` that accepts a few different file types. This works, no problem. I am interfacing with the API of my app (through SWAGGER API), and I need to send the file to the backend.

To do this, I am trying to use the following:

```
function upoadFile(){
    var myHeaders = = new Headers()
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Token ${Cookies.get("token")}`)

    var formdata = new FormData()

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: formdata,
        redirect: 'follow'
    }

    fetch(UPLOAD_URL, requestOptions)
}

<div className="file-uploader">
    <input 
        id="userfile"
        type="file"
        accept=".csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, .json, .yaml, .yml"
    />
    <Button onClick={() => {uploadFile()}} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</Button>
```

How can I get the data from the input element to populate the form data so the file can be sent to the API?

NOTE: I am using react in this application, so an answer using react will also work.

Comment: Can you include the code for the file input and how you are handling the saving of the file? I imagine you are saving it into state on upload

Comment: @RichardHpa I did include the input I'm using, maybe that's the problem. I will upload a section with more details

Comment: The `FormData` constructor takes a reference to the `form` element it should pull data from. Otherwise, there's no content in the `FormData` and you're posting nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I post form data and upload file with the JS fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137025/how-do-i-post-form-data-and-upload-file-with-the-js-fetch-api)

Comment: `onchange` of `<input type='file' />` a single file is accessed like `const singleFile = fileInputNode.files[0];`, then it can be `.append`ed to `FormData`. Id give the file a name as well, in [.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE based on the input code that was added.

```
function upoadFile(){
    var myHeaders = = new Headers()
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Token ${Cookies.get("token")}`)

    var formdata = new FormData();

    //This is the piece you are looking for
    var file = document.getElementById("userfile").files[0];
    formdata.append("usersFile", file);

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: formdata,
        redirect: 'follow'
    }

    fetch(UPLOAD_URL, requestOptions)
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to another answer as an answer. If the questions are the same, flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: That was the missing piece! Thank you!